# Conditional statement operands order

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-statements

Often I stumble upon following approach of defining conditional statement:

```
if(false === $expr) {
       ...
}
```

I have several questions about this.

1. Is there a point of using constant
   value (false, 1, 0, 123, 'string'
   etc) as a first operand instead of
   second in cases when second operand
   is not too long. For example, I
   would prefer to put false as the
   first operand when I have following
   statement:

   `if(false ===
   file_put_contents($file_path,
   $document['title'].PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.$document['body']))
   { ... }`
2. Does it make sense at all to use such approach in interpreted language which php is? I assume this comes from compiled languages such as Java when we want to avoid NullPointerException or in similar cases. Am I right?
3. What useful cases of using constant value as first operand do you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this comes from a quick-typer mistake like this in C:

```
 if( lenght = 0 ) { ... }
```

Where variables were unintentionally set to the compared value.  Reversing the intended comparison would generate a compiler error.

Comment: I find it ironic that in what you already refer to as a "quick-typer mistake", there is a typo ("lenght" instead of "length"). :P